# Getting the data id

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to get all the id's of my left and right div  for each rows and for the id's inside the div left, I want to store in array and arrange it to ascending order, and compare it to the id's of my left div. but I'm confuse how can I achieve on it.

Thank you in advance.

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="divider">
      <div id="left">
        <div data-id="310"><span data-id="310">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="312"><span data-id="312">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="320"><span data-id="320">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="311"><span data-id="311">Text here</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <div id="right">
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="320"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="310"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="312"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="311"> Text</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>      

<div class="row" id="row_1">
  <div class="divider">
    <div id="left">
      <div data-id="310"><span data-id="310">Text here</span></div>
      <div data-id="312"><span data-id="312">Text here</span></div>
      <div data-id="320"><span data-id="320">Text here</span></div>
      <div data-id="311"><span data-id="311">Text here</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="divider">
    <div id="right">
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="320"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="310"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="312"> Text</span></div>
      <div class="mixing"><span data-id="311"> Text</span></div>
    </div>
  </div>        
</div>  

<div class="btn-submit"><button id="go">Go</button></div>
</div>      
<script>
  $(function(){
    $('#go').on('click',function(e){
      $('div.content').each(function(index) {
        // getting first all the id's of left div for row_0 , my code is not correct
        var left_row_+index[] = $('#row_'+index).find('div#left').find('div').data('id');
        // arrange the left_row_+index to Asc Order
        // get the right id's store it to array , no need to arrange
        // compare two array
        if leftarray != rightarray
          return false // exit loop immediately no further checking or continuing the loop if not equal. else console.log("Looks good");
      });
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You're describing the approach you want to take, but not the outcome you want to achieve. What's your goal here? To see if an `id` exists in both elements? There's most likely a better way than what you are thinking.

Comment: @ScottMarcus, yes I want to acheive to check if the left div is equal to right div, it should the same in what index is the id's order. example already arrange to Asc order left_array=[310,311,312,320] then I will compare it to right_array = [311,310,312,320] if not same order it return false and exit the loop, mean it is error

Comment: Well, again, you're assuming that the best way to compare is to sort first, which may not be necessary.

Comment: But why is it not necessry ?

Comment: data-id of left div should be rearrange ? why not right ?

Comment: Nope the left should be arrange because in my backend I random it before I display to frotend. the right side should not be arrange.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `.map` to get all values from left div  then use `.sort()` to sort them . After sorting just use `.each` loop for right div then compare values of data-id and array finally print some messages.

***Demo Code*** :

```js
$(function() {
  $('#go').on('click', function(e) {
    //loop through left div
    $('div.left').each(function(index) {
      //get all values of left div
      var itsort = $(this).find('span[data-id]').map(function() {
        return $(this).data('id');
      }).get();
      itsort.sort(); //sort
      console.log(itsort)
      var flag = true;
      //loop through right div
      $(this).closest(".row").find(".right span[data-id]").each(function(index, value) {
        //check if both have same at given position or not
        if ($(this).data('id') != itsort[index]) {
          console.log($(this).data('id'))
          console.log("not good")
          flag = false;
          return false;
        }
      })
      if (flag == true) {
        console.log("All good..." + $(this).closest(".row").attr('id'))

      }
    });
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="content">
  <div class="row" id="row_0">
    <div class="divider">
      <div class="left">
        <div data-id="310"><span data-id="310">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="312"><span data-id="312">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="320"><span data-id="320">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="311"><span data-id="311">Text here</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="320"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="310"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="312"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="311"> Text</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row" id="row_1">
    <div class="divider">
      <div class="left">
        <div data-id="310"><span data-id="310">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="312"><span data-id="312">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="320"><span data-id="320">Text here</span></div>
        <div data-id="311"><span data-id="311">Text here</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="divider">
      <div class="right">
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="310"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="311"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="312"> Text</span></div>
        <div class="mixing"><span data-id="320"> Text</span></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="btn-submit"><button id="go">Go</button></div>
</div>
```

Comment: it always not good even I arrange to same Id

Comment: Hi, that was mistake on my end previous code was comparing both `right` div for one `left` div i have corrected that please check now .